# clickable div tag wont work with mouse over function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When my mouse over function is working, the clickable image wont send the value to my text file, but when I change my div tag to (this) its working but the mouse over function aint .

This is when the mouse over function is working bit not the send ranting value

```
  <div id="1"  onclick="SendRating(this,id);" onmouseover="rateStar(id)" value="> <img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

And this is when my function is sending the value, but the mouse over a'int working.

```
<div id="2"  onclick="SendRating(this.id);" ><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

This are my two functions that I'm using.

```
function SendRating(RatingValue){
var paramas = "rating="+RatingValue;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: "rating.php",
  data: paramas,
    success: function(responseText)
    {
    document.getElementById("ContentHolder").innerHTML = responseText;
    }
  }
);
}

function rateStar(rating){
    var i = 1;
    var ratings = '';
    for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
        if (i<=rating){
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src=\"star1.gif\">';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src=\"star.jpg\">';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the thing is now that its working, when i'm clicking outside the image, but not on the image ,wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're calling a js function from a html tag, using double quotes is best practice.

```
<div id="3"  onclick="SendRating(this.id);" onmouseover="rateStar(id);"><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

this will work

Comment: Hmm, cant get i rate anyway =/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes around `rateStar(id)`:

```
<div id="3"  onclick="SendRating(value);" onmouseover="rateStar(id)"><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a variable called `value`, which doesn't exist. Maybe you want to use this.id?

```
<div id="3"  onclick="SendRating(this.id);" onmouseover="rateStar(this.id)"><img src="star.jpg"></div>
```

Also, notice that I've wrapped rateStar(this.id) in quotes.